# How to change all CJK punctuation to a different font face gracefully?

Tags: fonts

Though Noto Sans CJK provides four versions: JP, KR, TC, and SC, and they are similiar but subtle different (see the 1st and 2nd line), I want to set all of the CJK characters to font TC, except CJK punctuation (，。「」……, etc) to font SC (as the 4th line).

I currently use preprocessing bash script to replace them by command `sed`; however that is just a workaround. How to change all CJK punctuation to a different font face gracefully?

In other words, how to replace all `。` with `{\punctfont。}`?

```
% !TEX program = xetex
\documentclass{ctexart}

\setCJKmainfont[SlantedFont=Noto Sans CJK TC]{Noto Sans CJK TC}
\newCJKfontfamily\punctfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}

\begin{document}

\texttt{TC}: 角、亮、空、窗、誤。

\texttt{SC}: {\punctfont 角、亮、空、窗、誤。} \\

我能吞下玻璃，而不傷身體。

我能吞下玻璃{\punctfont，}而不傷身體{\punctfont。}   % Expectation!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can do this with `XeTeXinterchartoks`. See [How to set a particular glyph to be of a particular typeface in XeLaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/331756) and [Font selection in XeTeX for specific characters](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/10248) for examples.

Comment: Also, there's a `PunctFamily` option for the package, but since the documentation is all in Chinese, I don't know what it does.